# Varnish - stale-while-revalidate doesn't appear to revalidate

Tags: caching, varnish, cache-control

We are using Varnish cache 6.2 to sit in front of our WebAPI backend.
The backend is sending a cache-control header back on certain requests, for things that we can cache for a bit longer.

However - should the backend go down, and stay down, we send stale-while-revalidate of an hour.

So a typical cache-control response header from our backend looks like:

```
public, max-age=30, stale-while-revalidate=3600
```

In our Varnish VCL we have added a routine that stops background fetch on certain errors. This is to stop the bad response from the backend from entering the cache:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (beresp.status == 500 || beresp.status == 502 || beresp.status == 503 || beresp.status == 504)
    {
        if (bereq.is_bgfetch)
        {
            return (abandon);
        }

        set beresp.ttl = 1s;
    }
}
```

The problem we are facing is simple - Varnish does not update the item in the cache after Max-Age expires, even though the backend is available. (And changes have occurred to the response)
We have seen issues where the responding "Age" header from Varnish exceeds 200s, with the wrong response. We have also seen cases where the "Age" header is 1-3s, which would indicate a background fetch (or normal fetch) has occurred.

This happens often enough that we notice it - but not on every request.

I have tried a simple "pass", such as the following in Varnish:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    return(pass);
}
```

However, this appeared to have no effect.

Could there be anything else with Varnish setup that could cause the situation above?

**EDIT**, as per comment, this is a small thing we add to each sub that interacts with our request, to see what actually happened:

```
sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.uncacheable) {
        set req.http.x-cache = req.http.x-cache + " uncacheable" ;
    } else {
        set req.http.x-cache = req.http.x-cache + " cached" ;
    }

    set resp.http.x-cache = req.http.x-cache;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    set req.http.x-cache = "hit";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the expected behavior. Once the object if fetched from the backend side for the first time (i.e. `t=0`), Varnish caches it setting `beresp.ttl` to `30s` and `beresp.grace` to `3600s`. Then, if you request the object to Varnish when `t=3000`, the old object will be delivered to the client side (i.e. `Age: 3000`) and an asynchronous background fetch will be triggered in order to refresh the cached object. If you request again the object to Varnish when `t=3001`, if the background fetch already completed its job, a fresh object will be delivered (i.e. `Age: 1`). The following test illustrates this behavior:

```
varnishtest "..."

server s1 {
    rxreq
    txresp -hdr "Cache-Control: public, max-age=1, stale-while-revalidate=60" \
           -hdr "Version: 1"

    rxreq
    txresp -hdr "Cache-Control: public, max-age=1, stale-while-revalidate=60" \
           -hdr "Version: 2"
} -start

varnish v1 -vcl+backend {
} -start

client c1 {
    txreq
    rxresp
    expect resp.http.Version == 1
    expect resp.http.Age == 0

    delay 5.0

    txreq
    rxresp
    expect resp.http.Version == 1
    expect resp.http.Age == 5

    delay 0.1

    txreq
    rxresp
    expect resp.http.Version == 2
    expect resp.http.Age == 0
} -run

varnish v1 -expect client_req == 3
```

In order to refresh the object synchronously once the item in the cache consumes its TTL, you need to play with `req.grace` during `vcl_recv`. You probably want to set it to `0s` if the backend is healthy. Please, check https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-grace.html#misbehaving-servers for details.

Comment: ... or perhaps you simply want to play with a lower `stale-while-revalidate`. It depends a lot on your goal.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! I had considered this previously. However we can go for an hour without the copy in cache ever being updated. We have thousands of requests - so Varnish should make some backend request to refresh data during that time, but does not appear to. Any other ideas about what could be happening here?

Comment: Any hit on the same URL (really on the same hash id) after the 30s TTL will always trigger the background fetch. It's hard to know what's going on without more info, but one possible option is that you are not really hitting the same object (e.g. perhaps you're doing something creative in `vcl_hash`, perhaps your backend responses contain funny `Vary` headers, etc.).

Comment: Hmm, vary headers. There's a thought. I will check into those. We also have a small section which dictates what happened with the request in the x-cache response header. I've edited that into the first post here. as pasting examples into comments is awful. This typically shows "hit cached" when we see the issue, unless the age is 0, then we see "miss cached"

Comment: If you're able to reproduce the issue, best approach is doing it using `curl` + some filtering header (e.g. `-H "X-TROUBLESHOOTING: 1"`) + `varnishlog -g request -q "ReqHeader:X-TROUBLESHOOTING"`. That log will show what really is going on.

Comment: Hey Carlos - perhaps i'm going about this all wrong. This morning after a fresh deploy, things appear to have worked as expected. The first request (and subsequent that were made before the backend response was completed) delivered the "stale" content. However, requests afterwards received new content, as you would expect. I do wonder though - the idea here is to safeguard against a sick backend, by serving content from the cache long after it's max-age. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Yes, as you said the idea is to safeguard against a sick backend, by serving content from the cache long after it's max-age. However, adding some VCL, you can check if the backend is healthy and, if so, limit the grace time to something reasonable using `req.grace`.